# XAMPP under Debian 6: cannot open "ssl://" URLs

Tags: php, openssl, xampp

I am having trouble opening URLs with the ssl:// scheme. Detailing:

`phpinfo()`: http://pastie.org/2391404

Sample code:

```
$socket = @fsockopen("ssl://cgw.ubb.bg", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$socket) {
  $err = "$errstr ($errno) - " . $socket;
  echo "Unable to connect. $err";
} else {
  echo "Connected.";
  fclose($socket);
}

echo PHP_EOL;
```

What I get in response is this:

`Unable to connect.  (0) -`

*(Yes, I did try to connect with telnet/browser/etc., the host/port combo is not the problem.)*

In other words, errno is 0, and no error message is provided.

When I put this in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`:

```
extension="openssl.so"
```

I am getting this error:

`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/openssl.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Alas, there is indeed no `openssl.so` file in there.

My XAMPP platform is: `i686-pc-linux-gnu`.

My question is:

Can I "cheat" somehow by just downloading the proper file and be done with it?
If not, how could I compile it from source and integrate it into XAMPP without ripping it apart?

**EDIT:**
It's a shame no viable suggestions were given thus far. Having in mind I used a ready-made XAMPP installation (basically unpacked the archive) and that XAMPP is pretty broadly used, I am very surprised nobody else stumbled upon this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your phpinfo(), openssl is available :

```
openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010
```

PHP allows building openssl into the core, and in that case it does not need to be in a separate extension. Does a file_get_contents("https://cgw.ubb.bg/") gives you the same error ?

EDIT : This seems to be a bug in openssl : I tried the sample I provided, and got the following error :

```
error:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message
```

After googling it, I found multiple bug reports / forum posts that all seem to say it is a problem between the openssl lib and the remote server. Apparently, forcing openssl to sslv3 corrects the problem, but I don't know how to do this with php.

Some bug reports (not related to php) :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/595415

http://forum.parallels.com/printthread.php?t=82502

Comment: Sorry for this taking several days, been very busy. Tried your code snippet, here is the response:

`error:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message in test1.php on line 3`
`Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in test1.php on line 3`
`Warning: file_get_contents(https://cgw.ubb.bg/): failed to open stream: operation failed in test1.php on line 3`

The line is:

`$data = file_get_contents('https://cgw.ubb.bg/');`

Can you help with this? I am gonna go look at these bugs now.

Comment: Sadly these links don't help. :/

Comment: After all, I ended up coding the feature I need directly on the live server (where the problem doesn't exist). Couldn't really find any solution despite the hours I spent on Google on this. Marking this as the answer, because even though it didn't solve anything, it at least contained some info. ;)

Answer (score 1):

After losing few hours to debug this problem on debian (squeeze with libssl0.9.8 installed) I've found a solution.
I'm using a dotdeb.org php version: php5-cgi 5.3.13-1~dotdeb.0 (doesn't seems to work with debian default package 5.3.3-7+squeeze13! - no_ticket is still missing in this version).

The solutions is to open the socket like this:

```
<?php
 $host = "ssl://cgw.ubb.bg";
 $context = stream_context_create(); 
 $result = stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'no_ticket',true);
 $socket = stream_socket_client($host.':443', $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

afterwards you simply use the socket as it was a fsockopen resource.